# why datepicker functionality is not working for two fields?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Here is my code**

Including the files for the datepicker:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="all" href="css/jsDatePick_ltr.min.css"/>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">

            window.onload = function(){
                new JsDatePick({
                    useMode:2,
                    target:"date",
                    dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"
                });
            };

       </script>
    </head>
```

Here i want to show the datepicker in two fields date and date1, but it is not showing in one field:

```
     <body>
         <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tr>
                 <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                 <td width="45" class="form_txt">Date : </td>
                 <td width="105"><input name="date"  style="color:black;background:white" type="text" id="date" style="" /></td>
                 <td width="87"><img src="../images/cal.jpg" width="36" height="18" /></td>
                 <td width="45" class="form_txt">Date1 : </td>
                 <td width="105"><input name="date"  style="color:black;background:white" type="text" id="date1" style="" /></td>
                 <td width="87"><img src="../images/cal.jpg" width="36" height="18" /></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: sry i bymistake i gave teo id's unique now check it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the same `id` attribute value on the page multiple times ... you need to create two `jsDatePick`s... like this :

```
 window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
      useMode:2,
      target:"date",
      dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"
    });
    new JsDatePick({
      useMode:2,
      target:"date2",
      dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"
    });
 };
```

and your HTML should then be

```
<td width="105"><input name="date"  style="color:black;background:white" type="text" id="date" style="" /></td>
<td width="105"><input name="date2"  style="color:black;background:white" type="text" id="date2" style="" /></td>
```

Notice the change on the second `input` to now use `date2` for `id` and `name`